# tracking down cause of 401 response from EF call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting the following exception when attempting to browse to my site :

[image]

The `configuration/staticcontent` endpoint is implemented like so:

```
    [HttpGet("staticcontent")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStaticContent()
    {
        return Ok(this.mapper.Map<StaticContentValueDto[]>(await this.staticContentValuesProvider.GetStaticContentValues()));
    }
```

.. .and the implementation of `GetStaticContentValues()` as follows:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<StaticContentValue>> GetStaticContentValues()
    {
        return await this.dbContext.StaticContentValues.ToArrayAsync();
    }
```

I suspect there might be an issue with AD authentication?

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist"; });
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization();

        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(o=>
        {
            o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            o.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
        

        string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        string reportingConnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ReportingConnection");

        services.AddDbContext<PnbIdentityDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        
        //20 or so other adddbcontext for sql server here
    //20 or so other adddbcontext for sql server here
        
        services.AddIdentity<PnbIdentityUser, PnbIdentityRole>(options => {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<PnbIdentityDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(CapsAutoMapperProfile));

        SessionConfigurator.Configure(services);
        AuthConfigurator.Configure(services, Configuration["Identity:TokenSecret"]);
        DiConfigurator.Configure(services);
        HangfireConfigurator.Configure(services, connection);
    }
```

Please note that `Identity:TokenSecret` is set in appsettings.json.

**What am I doing wrong? What is the reason for the 401 response?**

Comment: Since there is no authorization attribute on your HTTP method, I would check the authentication for your static web site in your App Service  (in Azure Portal) is set to Anonymous and not to an authentication provider.

Comment: im having a tough time finding where to check the authentication for the static web site.

Comment: If we talking off the shelf auth then its in the config file within the service. Check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration-overview. Right at the top talks about application config and how it affects authentication/authorization. Hopefully it helps (if it does let us know and i'll put it up as answer)

Comment: @AndrewHalil any chance you can point me to where i can configure authentication ?

Comment: @Aeseir i think im following what you're saying but i dont see where to configure this in the portal

Comment: ill post a 500 bounty asap

Comment: @AlexGordon you need to create the file and then upload it to the appropriate location. Have a ready of this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings#uploading-application-settings

Comment: Btw I am assuming you are using Azure Static Web App as opposed to Static Web App via Azure Storage

Comment: To authentication and authorization on your azure static webapp please refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization

Comment: Also you can refer this links for proper error handling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0  ,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0 ,  https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/error-handling/samples  . May it help

Answer (score 0):

> any chance you can point me to where i can configure authentication ?

Thank you [Ken W MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4800789/ken-w-msft) , Posting your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384302/adding-authentication-on-azure-static-web-apps) as answer to help other community members.

"Yes, it is possible. Azure Static Web Apps provides a **streamlined authentication** experience. By default, you have access to a series of pre-configured providers, or the option to register a custom provider.

- Any user can **authenticate** with an enabled provider. Once logged in, users belong to the  `anonymous`  and  `authenticated`  roles by default.
- Authorized users gain access to restricted routes by rules defined in the **staticwebapp.config.json** file. Users join custom roles via provider-specific invitations, or through a custom Azure Active
- Directory provider registration.
- All authentication providers are enabled by default.

  - To restrict an authentication provider, block access with a custom route rule.
- Pre-configured providers include:

  - Azure Active Directory
  - GitHub
  - Twitter

**Reference:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization ''