# Adding authentication on Azure Static Web Apps

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-static-web-app

I have deployed a very simple Azure Static Web Apps in which I deploy a simple documentation site powered by mkdocs (HTML and CSS). I would like to know if it is possible to implement some kind of authentication through Azure AD/MSAL in which only enterprise users could log in using their email and password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  Azure Static Web Apps provides a streamlined authentication experience. By default, you have access to a series of pre-configured providers, or the option to register a custom provider.

- Any user can authenticate with an enabled provider. Once logged in,
  users belong to the `anonymous` and `authenticated` roles by default.
- Authorized users gain access to restricted routes by rules defined in
  the staticwebapp.config.json file. Users join custom roles via
  provider-specific invitations, or through a custom Azure Active
- Directory provider registration.
- All authentication providers are
  enabled by default.

  - To restrict an authentication provider, block
    access with a custom route rule.
- Pre-configured providers include:

  - Azure Active Directory
  - GitHub
  - Twitter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization